# How can I check if an image exists with jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, exists

I'm sure you've seen this question many times, but i will asure you that this is different.
I want to know how to check if an image exists using the path to the image with a url variable.
I would like something like this:

```
if ($('url').length ) {
    $(".mainContent").html("File exists");
} 
else
    $(".mainContent").html("File does not exists");`
```

Hope you can help me soon...

Comment: Check if the element exists in the DOM, or if the image is actually there, on the server ?

Answer (score 0):

For images that might exist i find most elegant solution is useing $ajax, like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_image.jpg',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "image",
    success: function() {
        /* function if image exists (setting it in div or smthg.)*/
    },
    error: function(){
       /* function if image doesn't exist like hideing div or setting default image*/


      } 

})
```

But just to be warned some people insist on useing GET instead of POST but
I didn't have any problems and it works like a charm